# Replace the brackets in column value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a column called 'Timestamp' in dataframe. It has values in the form of lists joined by comma. I want to combine these different lists into single list. I am able to replace single character, but I am getting error when I do it as a whole how can I do this?

Example: 1 value of 1 row of column is ['2021-10-03 05:29:39.199'],['2021-10-03 06:58:55.584']
I am not able to create dataframe for this value.

[image]

Code I am using is

```
inputData["Timestamp"] = inputData["Timestamp"].str.replace('],[', ',')
```

But I am getting error.

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: what error? share sample of the df please

Comment: i added the error

Comment: The content seems to be valid Python. `ast.literal_eval()` could be helpful.

Comment: I think you can add a function as the second argument in .replace, or maybe str.replace("],[", ",")

Comment: Are you sure those characters are really in the column?  Or is it actually a Python list object?

Comment: yes those characters are in the value. i am able to replace it one by one, but I am not able to do it together

Comment: Does this help `str.replace(r"'],['" , ",")` ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use *[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)* which can *safely evaluate an string containing a Python
expression.*. With your current format it returns a tuple of lists.

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("['time1'], ['time2']")
(['time1'], ['time2'])
```

So you can apply this function across your `Timestamp` column.

```
inputData["Timestamp"] = inputData["Timestamp"].apply(lambda x: [t[0] for t in ast.literal_eval(x)])
```

Comment: It worked. But can you explain what kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: and i will approve this but after some time. i want to check other answers as well.  a simple one maybe

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will solve your problem:

```
str.replace(r"'],['" , ',')
```

Use this instead of your code:

```
inputData["Timestamp"] = inputData["Timestamp"].str.replace(r"'],['" , ',')
```

Comment: Nope. Still getting same error